# SQL correlated subqueries

Tags: sql, subquery, correlated-subquery

I have been working on this exercise on Codecademy for several days and still couldn't understand the logic behind it.Below is the exercise and code:

It would  be interesting to order flights by giving them a sequence number based on time, by carrier.
For instance, assuming flight_id increments with each additional flight, we could use the following query to view flights by carrier, flight id, and sequence number:

```
SELECT carrier, id,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM flights f
        WHERE f.id < flights.id
          AND f.carrier=flights.carrier) + 1 AS flight_sequence_number
FROM flights;
```

I can understand that `f` is a virtual form of table `flights`, but what does `f.id < flights.id` do? Does it mean that SQL compares each row in `f` with each row in `flights` like

compare MQ 17107 with MQ 7869,

compare MQ 17107 with MQ 2205,

compare MQ 17107 with MQ 14979

……

compare MQ 7869 with MQ 2205,

compare MQ 7869 with MQ 14979

……

Beside, what does this `COUNT(*)` really count? And why the`+1`?

This is the result image: [query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOEe2.jpg)

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Count the number of flights before the current id, and add 1.

Comment: Good programming practice has two different table aliases. E.g. f1 and f2 here.

Comment: With [modern SQL](http://modern-sql.com/slides) this can be done a lot easier using a simple window function: `row_number() over (partition carrier order by id)` - no need for a subquery.

Comment: @jarlh thanks and could you please tell me what does f.id < flights.id do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query selects records from table flights. For each record it selects carrier, id and the flight_sequence_number.

So for every record in flights the subquery gets executed. It reads the table flights again, but only takes records with the same carrier and a flight ID smaller than the one of the main record. In order to talk about the main query record and the sub query record, you need one or two table aliases, for otherwise both records would be called flight as in flight.id, and it would not be clear which one you are talking of. So the table in the inner query gets the alias f. Now you can compare f.id < flights.id and f.carrier = flights.carrier.

COUNT(*) counts hence all records lower than a main record's flight ID for its carrier and thus numbers the carrier's rows. For the smallest ID you find no smaller IDs so the count is 0 and you add one thus getting row number 1. For the second smallest you find one record with a smaller ID, hence you get count 1, add 1 and get row number 2 and so on.

The results will look better, when you add an order by clause `ORDER BY carrier, id`, so you show the results in the order used.

As has been mentioned, several modern DBMS offer analytic functions, such as `ROW_NUMBER` and the query becomes much simpler:

```
select 
  carrier, 
  id, 
  row_number() over (partition by carrier order by id) as flight_sequence_number
from flights
order by carrier, id;
```

Comment: I am still absorbing your answers. But thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You have a list of flights with a flight_id that tells you the sequence of all flights relative to each other. What the query you're looking at is trying to do, is get the sequence of each flight in relation only to flights of the same carrier. For example, if I asked you what was the 50th flight, it would be easy since you could just look up the flight with flight_id = 50. But if I asked you what with the 50th US Airlines flight, you wouldn't have any idea with the table you're given without a bit of aggregation or use of partitions.

Let's look at a simple select query. If you would select all carriers of a given type A, you would get something like this:

```
SELECT flight_id, carrier
FROM flights
WHERE carrier = A

flight_id, carrier
------------------
    4,       A
    9,       A
    10,      A
    18,      A
    20,      A
    25,      A
    26,      A
```

However `flight_id` is no longer a sequence number when we're only looking at carrier A. Flight with id 4 isn't the 4th flight of our results (which is flight 18). We could then aggregate the data so we have the sequence of each flight relative to flights of the same carrier. So what we have to do is count the number of flights of the same type before each row to get its sequence. Flight 4 has no earlier flights of type A, so it would have a sequence of 1 (0 flights before it, we add 1 to make the sequence start at 1). Flight 9 has 1 flight before it so we have sequence 2 (1 flight before + 1 offset = 2).

We need to do this for every flight in our results, so we can include a subquery in the select part of our query. A subquery in the select will be just like another select query, but will allow you to use the data in the outer query, and does this for every row returned in the outer query's results.

For what we want to do (find the sequence number of flights based on their order and their carrier), the subquery will compare each rows id's with all rows in the same table, if it is less than the current row's id, it is a flight before it and will be in the subquery's results. COUNT aggregates the results of this subquery so it's one value. We also ensure all results in our subquery matches the carrier of the current row we're looking at in our main query. We have to use an alias for this subquery since it's selecting from the same table and would be ambiguous otherwise, which is why it uses the alias 'f' to distinguish it from the main query. We can also give the results of this subquery a name of flight_sequence_number, which is stored in a new column. This will let you easily know the sequencing of all flights, as well as the sequence of flights relative to the same carrier.

Comment: Thank you for making it so clear. That clarifies everything for me.